# MySql table operations do not terminate

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, database-performance

I was creating a big table (30 columns * 10 million rows) by a join operation. And it kept running for a few days (on a big server) so I had to terminate the creation query.

However, this table still exists and I am unable to drop, delete, select, a simple (select count(*)), rename, or even a describe operation!
I can't drop the whole database because I have other important tables.
So how can I get rid of that table from my database?

I tried many solutions but none of them worked. I tried:

```
drop table badtable;
delete from badtable where 1 = 1; --always true 
delete from badtable where 1 = 1 limit 100; --never terminated
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message returned? Did you try TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name?

Comment: What happens after the drop operation?

Comment: Is there a other operation that use this table. use **SHOW PROCESSLIST** to find out

Comment: Have a try on this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80695/deleting-data-from-a-large-table-with-replication

Comment: @Tim: there is no error message returned. it just keeps "executing" forever so I have to kill it every time.

Answer (score 0):

It is an InnoDB table, correct?  When you terminated the create query, it set about to "rollback" what you had done.  Yuck.

By now, the situation has uncorked itself, yes?

Next time, build the table in, say, 1000-row chunks -- each chunk being COMMITted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ANALYZE TABLE` or `REPAIR TABLE`? If there's an error you can repair the table, then try deleting it.